# Subir imágenes a servidor con Xampp para usarlas en HTML

Tags: html

Me gustaría saber si es posible subir imágenes a mi servidor con Xampp para poder utilizarlas en un HTML, ya que estoy utilizando imágenes propias, pero me gustaría poder utilizar urls para asegurarme de que dichas imágenes se carguen correctamente.

Comment: Hola user, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Lo más importante es haberlo intentado. Sobre tu intento nos contextualizas en los problemas concretos que tienes y sobre ello podemos ayudarte. Si no lo has intentado, investiga y prueba. Después has de [edit] la pregunta para añadir la informacion que falta segun [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIÓN A LO PEDIDO: no puedes hacer lo que pides desde xamp en local, necesitas un servidor web para alojar las imágenes que te ofrezca una URL por imágen.
(respuesta editada)

Comment: En realidad eso ya lo estoy haciendo, y al acceder a mi html desde localhost todo funciona correctamente. El problema es que pretendo enviar este contenido por correo y, al hacerlo, si la imagen que he añadido no ha sido añadida mediante url sino por ruta a mi carpeta, la imagen no se ve. Es por eso que quería poder subir imágenes al servidor para así poder referenciarlas con urls. Perdón si no me he explicado bien y gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Obviamente, no puedes enviar imágenes locales, para eso sube las imágenes a un servidor pero ese servidor  no puede ser tu xampp en local.. tiene que ser un servidor web,  busca por Internet algún servidor que te permita alojar la imágenes y que te devuelva una url

Comment: Gracias, pensaba que se podía con xampp, no sabía que tenía que hacerlo con un servidor web.

Comment: De nada. Suerte